# How to import test data if I can't have an __init__.py in my tests folder?

Tags: python, unit-testing

According to http://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html, I should avoid putting **init**.py files in my test directories. This will prevent me from importing modules from my test directories.

However, sometimes I need to have modules containing test data. For example, inside my tests folder, I might have a module, test_data.py,  containing nothing but XML strings or Python dicts. However, if I have no **init**.py file inside my tests folder I won't be able to access test_data.py.

What is the recommended way of allowing me to access test data/modules from my tests, while making them inaccessible to the main package?

Comment: Just add an `__init__.py` and be done with it? Note however that your test is probably going to be run *without a package*, so a direct `import test_foo`, not `import tests.test_foo`. You could just add the dirname of the `__file__` value to your path at the top to be able to import any modules that live in the same directory.

Comment: Rather than XML strings and Python dicts, why not store XML and JSON files?